# My routes don't seem to exist, but I don't understand why

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

Fairly new to web development, so it's quite likely that this is a simple mistake on my part, but I've tried figuring this out for the past hour and I've got nothing.

Here's my current code, after I've stripped it down to the bare minimum, still not working.

app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
require('dotenv').config();

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const apiPath = process.env.API_PATH || '/api/v1';

const gamesRoute = require('./routes/gamesRoute');

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.use(`${apiPath}/games`, gamesRoute);

// Start server, binding it to specified port
app.listen(port, function() {
    // Log a message when server is successfully started
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send("test");
});
```

gamesRoute.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', async function(req, res) {
    console.log("test");
    res.json({ msg: "test" });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Response (I'm using the VSCode extensions 'humao.rest-client', and calling `GET localhost:3000/api/v1/games`):

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 151
Date: Wed, 10 Jan 2024 11:46:35 GMT
Connection: close

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot GET /api/v1/games</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

I also get nothing in the console.
My assumption is that I'm making a very basic mistake, but I have no idea what it is.

I've tried looking at tutorials, both on youtube, the express documentation, and random posts. Based on what I've found, I'm doing things correctly, so I'm in a bit of a stump. I've also looked through a bit more than half of the questions stack overflow recommended that might be duplicates, and none of them seem to solve my issue, unless I'm just too dumb to get it.

Comment: Works for me,  what if you just put http://localhost:3000/api/v1/games  into your browser?  Also try console logging apiPath, make sure it's `/api/v1` and it's not be overridden with Env var.

Comment: I have copied your code 1:1 and it works for me. Are you sure you didn't change the base api path via environmental variables by accident?

Comment: Are you sure you are actually running the server? You said you get nothing in the console. At the very least you should be getting a message that Server is running on port.

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski  I think its running -> `X-Powered-By: Express`

Comment: Then why are they not getting any logs in the console? Maybe they are running an outdated version, ex. they started a server without their route, and didn't restart it afterwards

Comment: @Keith
Yup, as expected, it was something stupid, the environment variable was 'api/v1' instead of '/api/v1' haha.
Thanks you.

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski
Yes it was indeed the environment variable, thank you!

Comment: Voting to close the question as not reproducible/caused by a typo

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski  This might be one of those questions that might be worth keeping open.  If you think about, if another user did the same mistake and then did a search and found this, it could well help them fix it themselves.  So my comments & yours might help others in the future.. :)

Answer (score 1):

My issue was indeed simple and stupid. The environment variable I used was overriding `/api/v1`, and in the `.env` file I had only put `api/v1` without the first `/`.

Answer (score -1):

if you want use router.use('/') in gamesRoute file than const router = express.Router() is valid but you need to use routes than you will use here same as atteched code.

gamesRoute.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express();

router.get('/', async function(req, res) {
    console.log("test");
    res.json({ msg: "test" });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: This is not a correct way to create an express router. Moreover it doesn't solve the issue

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski  is correct, `Router` is a cut down App, it will work using `express()` but your adding overhead that's not required.   To be fair, I think very very old versions of express this was how it was done.